# css table column issue?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

Hey guys,

I am using bootstrap 3 ,i have created a table which is of responsive type .The table is divided into 4 columns and each column is separated by white space.But as per my requirement i dont need the white space after first columns as shown in image with red arrow .

To the table class i have used properties border-collapse: separate and border-spacing: 10px 0;
border spacing here is responsible for column seperation.Please help how to do remove this single white space of the table made by border spacing ... please Find js fiddle link in below comments

Comment: Provide us a demo, as far as I see, it's white space issue

Comment: Hey Alien thank but i have applied here  border spacing to td tag which resulted into this seperation of columns which is expected but for now is it possible to remove the spacing between the frst 2 columns

Comment: we need source code to figure out whats wrong

Comment: @Kingisback Throw us a fiddle and I will solve for you

Comment: hey see this http://jsfiddle.net/84LXL/1/

Comment: hey Alien got the link of fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You could , fill that white space with a border (giving the relative position and some other extra CSS) :
for instance :

```
.buynow-product-comparisions table, .table-product-comparision table {

}
.buynow-product-comparisions th, .table-product-comparision th, .buynow-product-comparisions td, .table-product-comparision td {
    background-color: #c9e8fa;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666;
}
.table-product-comparision th.personal-head, .table-product-comparision th.cloudworkgroup-head, .table-product-comparision th.enterprise-head {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.buynow-product-comparisions td.bg-white {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}
.buynow-product-comparisions td.plan-feature-text, .table-product-comparision td.plan-feature-text {
    background-color:#c9e8fa;
    color: #666;
    text-align: left;
}
.table-product-comparision th.attribute-title {
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: right;
    width: 30%;
}
.cloud-personal {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #4d4d4d;
    padding: 12px 0;
}
.table-product-comparision td.vtypes {
    color: #26a2ed;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.table-product-comparision td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #dedede;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
}
.table-product-comparision td.plan-feature-text {
    background: #ffffff;
}
.table-responsive.buynow-page, .table-responsive.buynow-page {
    padding: 0;
}
td + td {
    border-right:10px solid white;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/84LXL/4/ (some css removed and mostly added on last lines )

Comment: if you need the stripes (not seen in your fiddle), then they could be applyed as repeating linear-gradient & background-size in em and use rgba color to fill backgrounds and shadows

Comment: Hey GCyrillus thanks but i just dont want the white space between column 1 and column 2 other 2 white spaces i need

Comment: have you tried collapse or spacing:0 and use border or padding for the last 2 tds , see selector like nth-last-of-type(2);

Comment: Hey nth type is good option but it does not work in ie 8 :( .I tried spacing 0 for td's of first column but doesn't work

Comment: spacing works for all or none , try to insert empty tds otherwise, off i go, good luck

Comment: take a look a this with border-right and some update of your CSS (bootstrap is too often unfriendly to tune as it seems on many forums ) http://jsfiddle.net/84LXL/4/ (removed position:relative and got rid of sep in css, no longer needed in html actually :)

Comment: Thanks Gcyrillus , this is what i have been waiting for .:P